# Does the Skype Chat button still appear in Word Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, word, collaboration

Currently testing collaboration functionality in Word, and according to the following Microsoft Office guides below, they show that when two people are collaborating on the same Word Online document a Chat button appears next to their name, by clicking on this it allows you to chat in the document using Skype.

https://blogs.office.com/en-us/2016/03/07/collaboration-in-office-chat-with-your-co-editors-in-real-time-via-skype/

and

https://blogs.office.com/en-us/2016/05/25/office-online-chat-with-your-co-editors-in-real-time/

However, I'm unable to see this in my tenant. These documents were written back in March 2016 and May 2016. Does this feature still exist today?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's platform-dependent whether it works. On Linux it sometimes shows up for me and other times not, but even when it does, it doesn't actually work. (Tried in Firefox and Chrome.)

But on Windows with Chrome, it's there and it Just Works(TM).